# Hyper-V work on a windows 7 32-bit machine

Tags: windows, windows-7, 32-bit, hyper-v

Will Hyper-V work on a windows 7 32-bit machine? And if so does anyone know how to set it up on HP EliteBook 8530p laptop? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason you couldn't find the answer to this question is because you were searching the wrong sites. It's not a programming-related question, so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. However, it has already been answered on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/9274/hyper-v-on-windows-7) and [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/29575/does-windows-7-support-hyper-v).

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not.

- It is 64 bit.
- It is not avaialble as part of Windows 7.

All that is there to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Hyper-V, but you do have access to Windows XP virtual environment in windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V is a Role on Windows Server 2008 or available as a standalone server. The standalone version is simply the Server 2008 Core with Hyper-V enabled, no Gui, just a simple console. The standalone edition is available for free, as far as i know.